# Quote meaning: A wife is essential to great longevity

Tags: meaning, quotes

Can anyone please explain to me the meaning of this quote?

> A wife is essential to great
>   longevity; she is the receptacle of
>   half a man's cares, and two-thirds of
>   his ill-humor. -Charles Reade

Comment: Here's a similar quote: *Wives are young men's mistresses, companions for middle age, and old men's nurses.* - Francis Bacon

Comment: There is in the Bible an excellent paeon of praise to the wife of noble character.  The Old Testament book of Proverbs, chapter 31, verses 10-30 is a must-read for those who have a high view of the role of wives in society.  It is a refreshing alternative to television's "The Real Housewives of Orange County"!  Here's an excerpt:  "A wife of noble character: who can find?  She is worth far more than rubies.  Her husband has full confidence [in her] and lacks nothing of value.  She brings him good, not harm, all the days of her life."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the interpretation of literature.

Answer (score 8):

This means that having a good wife allows you to live longer. That's because a husband can give half of his worries to his wife ("she is the receptacle of half a man's cares"), and will take out his bad moods on her ("and two-thirds of his ill humor"). She presumably puts up with this.

Pity the wife, though.

Comment: Yup, that's the meaning. Too bad it's not true. http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/living-single/200902/no-getting-married-does-not-make-you-live-longer

Comment: It might be a little sarcastic too. Hard to tell without knowing the context.